# openssl smime demo programs (smenc.c and smdec.c) produces inconsistent result

Tags: encryption, openssl, smime

I am looking at the sample programs under openssl-1.0.1e/demos/smime. Here are my steps:

```
gcc -o smenc smenc.c -lcrypto
gcc -o smdec smdec.c -lcrypto
./smenc     -> This encrypts encr.txt into smencr.txt
./smdec     -> This decrypts smencr.txt into encrout.txt
```

Now compare the round-trip results with the original:

```
vimdiff -b encr.txt encrout.txt
```

You can see the round-trip result has an extra '\r' for each line. Does someone know at what stage those '\r' chars are added?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1.0.1 is quite old and out of support btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually in smime(1) manpage. Look for "-binary" tag. During encryption, if "-binary" flag is not used, the code will replace all EOL with "\r\n".

To be a good example, I think the demo code should have round-trip consistency. To have this behavior, you can modify smenc.c to have flags line like this:

```
  int flags = PKCS7_STREAM|PKCS7_BINARY
```

I found it the hard way, though. For people who are interested in tracing openssl code, here is what I did:

- Download openssl-1.0.1e, run "./config --openssldir=" (otherwise you will get complaints about openssl.cnf, but this is easy to get around), then modify ./Makefile to replace "-O3" in CFLAGS with -g, then run "make".
- Under demos/smime, build the encrypt and decrypt code this way so you can trace crypto library as well, otherwise you are likely to link in the system libcrypto:

  ```
  gcc -g -o smdec smdec.c -L../../ -lcrypto -ldl
  gcc -g -o smenc smenc.c -L../../ -lcrypto -ldl
  ```
- Now you can run "gdb --args ./smenc" and break at SMIME_crlf_copy(). Run a backtrace, you can see how it gets there and how CRLF is added to every line.